# Is there a way to apply multiple "NOT" in an IF statement?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to compare two rows from Column A to Z and check if they have the same pattern.
With pattern I mean if in row 1 column A anything is written there must also be something written in row 2 column A.
Alternatively both can be empty.

The If statement is to be executed if the pattern doesn't match so:
Something written in A1 and nothing written in A2.

In the code I skipped the loop part since I guess its unnecessary for the problem.

```vb
If Not (A1 = "" And A2 = "") Or Not (Not A1 = "" And Not A2 = "") Then
    Boolean = False
End If
```

Comment: `Not (A1 = "" And A2 = "")` will be TRUE if one or both of A1 and A2 have something in them. `Not (Not A1 = "" And Not A2 = "")` will be TRUE if the bit in brackets is false, i.e. one or both of A1 and A2 are empty. I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion - I corrected my comment as the original was wrong.

Comment: Booth need to be empty, or both need something written within them. If thats NOT the case, execute the code in the if statement. Wouldnt `Not (A1 = "" And A2 = "") OR Not (A1 = "*" And A2 = "*")` achiev that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symplifying your boolean expression shows it always avaluate to true, so there is a problem here.

Quick boolean algebra lesson:

```
NOT(A AND B) = NOT(A) OR NOT(B)
NOT(A OR B) = NOT(A) AND NOT(B)
```

When applied to your expression, writing for simplicity `A1 = ""` as `A` and `A2 = ""` as `B`:

```
  Not (A And B) Or Not (Not A And Not B)
= Not(A) Or Not(B) or Not(Not(A)) or Not(Not(B))
= Not(A) Or Not(B) or A or B
= True
```

What you mean is, I believe, something like:

```
  Not((A and B) or (Not(A) and Not(B)))
```

Which may be simplified, but this impairs readability (what you want to check becomes less obvious).

Finally, you shouldn't write something like this:

```
If Expression
    Boolean = False
```

but rather:

```
Boolean = Not(Expression)
```

Assuming the variable assignment is not a placeholder for actual code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim i As Long, result As Boolean
For i = 1 To 25
    If Cells(1, i).Value = Cells(2, i).Value Then
        result = True
    Else
        result = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

You can modify this code for your purpose, but whenever a column has a different value in both first and second row, result will be false, and true if they are equal.

Columns can be treated both as letters or numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time trying to figure what you want to do with that line of code, but here is my shot at it.
It will return `Boolean = False` only if `A1` is empty and `A2` isn't, or if `A1` isn't empty but `A2` is.

```
If (A1 = "" and A2 <> "") OR (A1 <> "" and A2 = "") Then
    Boolean = False
End If
```

Comment: Sorry if the code is missleading but this would be what I wanted. I try it and give feed back in a few minutes ^^ Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula like the below to evaluate if every cell in a range is blank.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(range<>""))=0
```

and a similar formula to check if every cell is not blank:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(range=""))=0
```

and apply the formula using VBA, or else as a normal Excel formula.

Taken from this page:
https://exceljet.net/formula/all-cells-in-range-are-blank

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but my conclusion is that your statement will always evaluate to TRUE

[image]

A slightly different approach

```
Sub x()

Dim b As Boolean

b=(WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("A1:A2")) <> 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one about what I understand :

```
 if (A1<> "" and A2<>"") or  (A1= "" and A2="") then
     Boolean = False
 end if
```